# How can I claim an element after the patent has issued?

Tags: claims

A patent application that I filed in June 2010 was published in February 2012. It issued as a patent in October 2013.

I would like to claim an element disclosed in the specification in February 2014.

a. Is there any way of claiming the element now?

b. Can I reopen the prosecution and amend the independent claim with the element?

Answer (score 1):

As best as I can understand your question, it seems you may have made an error by claiming either too broadly or too narrowly.  You might want to consider pursuing a reissue application.  See MPEP Chapter 1400 ==> http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/mpep-1400.html.

In the future, ideally, you should file a continuation patent application prior to issuance of a patent.  This allows you to continue to mine the specification for additional claims.

Comment: "in the future"? Is there any reason that he cannot file a continuation patent now?

Comment: Yes, in order to file a continuation patent application codependency must be maintained.  Once the patent issues, there is no codependency and a continuation patent application can no longer be filed.

Comment: So that is so much more an argument for filling sooner than later.